# Does flashing the stock ROM repartition the device internal memory?

Tags: rom-flashing, partitions

After I have repartitioned my tablet I wonder what would happen if I flashed the stock ROM again.

Comment: Not the usual zip files meant to be flashed in recovery mode (it is possible though). But factory firmware flashers which work at bootloader or even lower level can manipulate partitions. Starting with Android 10 even OTA updates from OEMs will be able to resize dynamic partitions inside a super partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full firmware from the manufacturer can do that. You can see the flash sequence has a file similar to `gpt_both` or anything with GPT in the filename and is flashed to the partition **partition**. For example: `fastboot flash partition gpt_both.bin`

If there's no such file you can find, then the flash sequence is most likely not rebuilding the partition structure.